# Setting div to exactly the size of its child or background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have an image, part of which contains a stylized screen. I want text to show up on that screen. In order to make sure that the text doesn't stray off of the screen, I need to set the dimensions of the paragraph element based on the height and width of the image.

I've already made it so that the image is automatically resized to fit the window, without stretching or scrolling:

```
position: absolute;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
height: auto;
```

But IMG tags can't have children, so I can't put a child paragraph element that knows what size the image is.

So my next thought was to stick both the IMG and paragraph elements inside a containing DIV. That way, the DIV would expand to be the size of the image, and the paragraph could position itself based on that size. But the DIV's size is just 0x0; it doesn't automatically expand to contain the image. Is there a way to make the parent DIV the exact size of its child IMG?

Alternatively, I could use the background-image property of the DIV to contain the image, and not an IMG tag. But would there then be a way for the child paragraph element to access the size of its parent DIV's background image?

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working**?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself"***. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I'm not sure what additional information you'd like me to provide. And I'm not asking why the code in the question isn't working. The image's CSS is perfect; it's resizing itself exactly how it should. I'm just asking whether or not I can set its parent DIV to be equal in size.

Comment: You're basically presenting an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Chances are problem X can be solved much easier than solving problem Y, which can't be solved using CSS in this case. It would be possible with JavaScript but, again, it largely depends on your particular case, which we don't know much about.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, a code sample would be helpful… But if what you mean is having some text on top of an image positioned in relation to the size of the image, one option is to position the text absolutly and just translate it to the percentage value that correspond to the offset you're looking for:

```
.container {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   overflow: hidden;
   img {
      display: block;
   }
}

.copy {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   color: red;
   transform: translate(10%, 20%);
}

<div class="container">
   <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random/900x400" alt="">
   <div class="copy">
      Some text
   </div>
</div>
```

working example: https://codepen.io/md/pen/daJdjj